# Call function in document insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create "server side function" (custom JS function loaded in Mongo db) according to [autoincrement tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection). 
The main idea is to have function getNextSequence(collectionName), which returns autoincrement id for this collection. Trick is to have separate collection "counters" with document for each collection, that holds autoincrement status.

Anyway, I have created and loaded that function in Mongo and it works nicely via Mongo shell:

```
db.users.insert(
   {
     _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
     name: "Sarah C."
   }
)
```

It also works from NodeJS via eval:

```
db.eval('getNextSequence(\'test\')', function(err, result){...});
```

But I can't figur out, how to use it inline in document when inserting from NodeJS. 
I cannot write:

```
   {
     _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
     name: "Sarah C."
   }
```

as this would expect getNextSequence to be NodeJs method. Is there any expression form in NodeJS+MongoDB for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to call it in node the way you have specified above and then use the value that is returned in your insertion.

```
db.eval('getNextSequence(\'test\')', function(err, result) {
  db.users.insert({
      _id: result,
      name: "John Doe"
      ...
    }, function(err, result) {
         ...
    }})
});
```

For cleaner syntax, you could try using the npm package mongo-triggers:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongo-triggers

Comment: I was hoping I can spare this db call, but I gues it is driver-db engine thing and nothing better is available. Thanks.

Comment: @ooouuiii - I think the only other alternative would be to roll your own trigger(s) with something like this:

http://danielweberonline.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/creating-triggers-for-mongodb/

Comment: Wow I didn't know this :), thanks. For now I just sacrificed that one call for clarity, but this may be handy for some future use case. I'll see, if that passes performance test. Maybe another way could be to place the whole insert to eval. In this case, there is no problem to include there the function call. But then it would be wulnerable for some nosql injection.

Comment: `eval()` is deprecated

Comment: @LHCHIN - feel free to supply the correct solution/edit the answer. This answer is close to 7 years old so fingers crossed, there's undoubtedly a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

in the post method set a variable which requires db:
**var db = req.db;**
Then declare a variable for your db collection: 
**var collection = db.get('counter');**
then insert your items:

```
    collection.insert({
        _id: getNextSequence("userid"),
         name: "Sarah C."
         }, function (err, doc) {
             if (err) {
               // DO SOMETHING
             }
             else {
               // DO SOMETHING
             }
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for hint, I may explained it poorly. In this way, we don't overcome the problem, that NodeJS will try to call function getNextSequence, which is defined in mongoDb, not in NodejJs.